# Java Domain and DAO Mapper

Tags: java, spring, domain-driven-design

The structure of the project is that there are Domain objects that are used to perform some logical operations on them and DAO objects that are only used to save and read data from the database. And after reading the DAO object from the database there are mappers whose job is to convert the DAO object to the Domain version.

Sample of a Domain object:

```
public class User {
    UserId userId;
    String name;
    ShoppingCart shoppingCart;
    ...
}

public class ShoppingCart {
    ShoppingCartId shoppingCartId;
    float price;
    User user;
    ...
}
```

Sample of DAO objects:

```
public class UserDAO {
    Long id;
    String name;
    ShoppingCartDAO shoppingCart;
    ...
}

public class ShoppingCartDAO {
    Long id;
    float price;
    UserDAO user;
    ...
}
```

But there is a problem when the DAO object has a relation with another object and this relation is bidirectional.

For example:
User object has ShoppingCart object inside and ShoppingCart has User object inside in @OneToOne relation.

The idea of mappers is that they map the whole object so the mapper for the User object would rewrite regular fields into UserDAO and would run mapper for ShoppingCart so it can convert it so ShoppingCartDAO and assign it to UserDAO. But once it does so the mapper ShoppingCart mapper will try to map the User to DAO and it ends up in a loop of mappers calling each other.

Sample mapper:

```
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class UserDAOMapper {

    public static UserDAO toDAO(User user) {

        return UserDAO.builder()
                .id(user.getUserId().getId())
                .name(user.getName())
                .shoppingCart(ShoppingCartDAOMapper.toDAO(user.getShoppingCar())
                .build();
    }
}
```

How can I avoid such loops and at the same time keep the code simple? The only solution I see so far is the usage of Factory services that would take a list of arguments with objects inside the object and map it only if the passed argument is null.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that you tagged your question with `domain-driven-design`. One of the key principles in domain driven design is that every aggregate has one root and that operations on that aggregate happen via the root. Looking at the example that you provided it looks like that encapsulation is broken.

I recommend to rethink your design. Some questions that could help in that effort:

- Can a user exist without a shopping cart (for example when he has just logged in) or is he assigned an empty shopping cart during creation?
- Can a shopping cart exist without a user (likely not) -> This may be a pointer that all operations on shopping cart actually have to go via its aggregate root which is user. So now you could question why `User` needs to be an attribute of `ShoppingCart`, since `ShoppingCart` can never be accessed directly, it always has to be accessed via `User`.